# Better AUC on LOOCV than whole dataset

Tags: generalized-linear-model, cross-validation

I am doing LOOCV on a data set of 100 samples (50 cases and 50 controls). Based on the whole dataset I have made a signature predicting the cases (AUC=0.77) based on only 1 feature, where the selection criteria is that the feaure should be significant in the GLM-model. When I do the LOOCV I sometimes get 2 significant features, depending on which sample is removed, then both features will be include in the model, since the model is constructed to include all significant features. Since the LOOCV is including more features in total than the original signature, the AUC score is actually better in the LOOCV than the original signature. Is this supposed to happen? Should I define in the LOOCV that not more than 1 feature should be included since this is the case in the original feature?

```
loocv <- sapply(1:nrow(df.t), function(x) {
  loo.data <- df.t[-x,]
  ....glm.model....
  
  model <- glm(features, family=binomial(logit),data=loo.data)
  predict(model,newdata=df.t[x,],type=c("link"))
  list(mirs= features, model=model, prediction=predict(model,newdata=df.t[x,], type = "link"))
  
})
g <- roc(df.t$Group,predictor = unlist(loocv[3,]), data = df.t)
```

[image]